# Tests pass or fail depending on method of PHP Unit invocation

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a large number of tests in a PHP Unit test suite.

All tests will pass when running the complete suite, however when run individually, certain tests may pass or fail depending on how I call PHP Unit:

```
$ php phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --filter FooIntegrationTest

PHPUnit 5.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

................                                                  16 / 16 (100%)

Time: 3.97 seconds, Memory: 109.50MB

OK (16 tests, 36 assertions)
```

vs.

```
$ php phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml tests/Integration/FooIntegrationTest.php

PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..........F.F...                                                  16 / 16 (100%)

Time: 3.73 seconds, Memory: 111.75MB

FAILURES!
Tests: 16, Assertions: 36, Failures: 2.
```

The failures in question are unexpected results (i.e. the code runs just fine), no PHP errors or Exceptions.

The majority of tests will pass both ways, and there doesn't seem to be anything special about those tests that produce the above results.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that they seem to be running two versions of PHPUnit - 5.7.19 and 5.7.21.

Comment: ah yes I tested in different VM's to see if it may be a PHP Unit version issue.
However the problem persists regardless of version.

Comment: It was more a case of if they were running different versions, there is a potential for other differences (i.e. different phpunit.xml) or being run from a different directory (which would affect paths etc.).

Comment: Is there something that these failing tests have in common? (File access, particular DB access)

Comment: Both tests perform complex queries against a local Elasticsearch index. However I have other tests that perform similar queries with no issues.

Comment: Could it be worth adding one of those examples and see if there is an issue with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.... namespace conflict from an unrelated test class

`phpunit ... FooIntegrationTest.php` only opens & runs the single class file specfied

whereas `phpunit ... --filter FooIntegrationTest` will open every file in the suite to look for matching tests; which lead to a globally namespaced function in another file causing false pass.

Lesson learned: don't declare globally namespaced functions in unit test classes!